# How can I display image instead of displayed Image path name

Tags: php, magento-1.9, custom-post-type

I need to display product details on my custom page,

Code:

```
  <?php 
set_time_limit(0); //THIS SCRIPT JUST INITIALS THE PROFILE TO BE RUN VIA MAGENTO ADMIN "RUN PROFILE IN POPUP". Its the same thing as click just via this file that you can run via cron 
$profileId = 1; // SYSTEM - IMPORT/EXPORT - DATAFLOW PROFILES PROFILES <-- you need to go into your magento admin and grab the exact profile ID 
require_once 'app/Mage.php'; 

umask(0); 
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID); 
$sku = 10; //this sku you get it from your text box. 
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(array(
    'name',
    'sku',
    'price',
    'thumbnail' 
))->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array(
    'in' => $sku 
)); 
$imageHelper = Mage::helper('catalog/image'); 

foreach($_product as $prod) 
{
    $name = $prod->getName();
    $price = $prod->getPrice();
    $thumbnail = $imageHelper->init($prod, 'thumbnail')->resize(150, 220); 
} 

echo "Name: ", $name; 
echo "<br />";
echo "Sku: ", $sku; 
echo "<br />";
echo "Price: ", $price; 
echo "<br />";
echo "Image: ", $thumbnail; ?>
```

How can I display product image instead of image path.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your code is badly formatted and would probably even not parse like that. Also your question sounds too broad.

Answer (score 1):

I saw your original question with the code and I think you're using Magento
So you can do it like this

Load product by ID

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(.....)
```

Or get all products

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection() .....
```

Get product image

```
Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image') // You can change to another image code
```

Or get all media images

```
$_product->getMediaGalleryImages() // It's array, you need to loop through it to get image detail
```

**Display like image instead a url**

```
<img src="<?php echo $image_url ?>">
```

Take your time and read about this [HTML Images](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp)

Comment: <?php set_time_limit(0); //THIS SCRIPT JUST INITIALS THE PROFILE TO BE RUN VIA MAGENTO ADMIN "RUN PROFILE IN POPUP". Its the same thing as click just via this file that you can run via cron $profileId = 1; // SYSTEM - IMPORT/EXPORT - DATAFLOW PROFILES PROFILES <-- you need to go into your magento admin and grab the exact profile ID require_once 'app/Mage.php'; umask(0); Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID); $sku = 10; //this sku you get it from your text box. $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection() ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'sku',

Comment: Above is my code,, could u pls help me how can I do that.

Comment: You got the product collection already, just loop through it and print out product image url in image tag

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer:

```
echo "<img src='".$thumbnail ."'>";
```

Thank You @Hung Vo

Comment: Why you posted this instead of accepting Hung Vo's answer?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski : Please check his answer, actually the major modification on his answer,, so i put the exact answer for help to others...

Comment: if my reason valid, please remove downvote.. maybe this information useful others. because you did downvote for the right answer.